# Is there proof that the Prophet صلى الله عليه وسلم was made of Light?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, aqidah

Some believe he isn't just a human but made of Light - perhaps both human and Light. Anyway what is proof if any. I'm curious how the rest of the Ummah has overlooked this.

Comment: Why should the prophet pbuh be made of light, who says so? (see [ask]).

Comment: see this too https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35999/was-there-a-shadow-of-prophet-muhammad-peace-be-upon-him/36004#36004

Answer (score 1):

Several hadiths state that the Prophet MOHAMMAD (pbuh) was created from light of Allah [1,2]. But here is a point that must be considered. The meaning of this kind of ahadith refers to light truth of holy prophet and don't speak of physical existence of his Majesty.

On the other hand, in the level of material and physical presence, The Prophet (pbuh) was born like other humans, and has lived like others, though his live was, is and will be the best paradigm of religious living.

So there ares two truths or two facts about the Prophet (pbuh).

References: 
1. Biḥār al-Anwār, 1, p. 97

2. Same, vol 15, p. 24

Comment: This answer can be appreciated, since due to being short conveys the issue/answer, plus by submitting evidences (at least based on my notion)... Well done.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no proof that he was made of light. And to say “prophet Muhammad was made from light” this is totally false and exaggerating. Do you know when people used to love exaggeratedly with love towards Jesus Christ? This is something similar to it. And the only one who God Made from light are the angels only and Muhammad is only a human but he is a prophet.

And it clear that God Says:

> “Say (O Muhammad): I am only a man like you. It has been revealed to me that your Ilaah (God) is One Ilaah (God ___i.e. God)”

This means, he was made like a human being and not made from light. And he is 100% human.

Oh, and the body of the Prophet (peace and blessings of God be upon him) was blood and flesh and bone, and so on. He was created from a father and a mother, and had no existence before he was born.

And, “Their Messengers said to them:

> ”We are no more than human beings like you”

[Ibraaheem 14:11]

And also God Himself says:

> “Say (O Muhammad): ‘I am only a man like you. It has been inspired to me that your God is One God. So whoever hopes for the Meeting with his Lord, let him work righteousness and associate none as a partner in the worship of his Lord.” [al-Kahf 18:110]

So this means, that whoever told you that prophet Muhammad was created from light is false and you should not believe in what you hear it.

Remember this:

> ”Believe nothing of what you hear, and only half of what you see.”

And God knows best

---

Sources:

-https://islamqa.info/en/4509

Comment: For saying "no" you need a strong evidence it is easier to demonstrate or show that something exists than to show that it doesn't. Your statement might be a good start no more nor less. But if there's even a da'if hadith mentioning "light" in the context of the prophet pbuh your whole answer has lost any proof.

Comment: @Medi1Saif How can I prove?

Comment: @Medi1Saif How about now? Is it good?